# send comment meta with wordpress rest api

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to send a comment with wordpress rest api and it works, but I can't send meta data I put the data in "meta" object while sending post request but the data won't save in the database I have exactly the problem that is mentioned in this post:[Set comment meta REST API WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008833/set-comment-meta-rest-api-wordpress)
but nobody answered that.

```js
 var commentData = JSON.stringify({
    post: postId,
    author_name: nameVal,
    content: textVal,
    phone:phoneVal,
    meta:{
      phone:phoneVal,
    }
  });

  var ACTION_URL = apiUrl+'comments';

  fetch(ACTION_URL, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: commentData,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.json());
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error)
    });
```

in wordpress documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#schema-meta
says that you have to put meta data in meta object but while the response is ok and the comment will be submitted successfully the "phone" meta data will not be saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, solution is to add these using register_meta() which will add the meta fields to the schema of the comment.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/

In my case the following worked:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    register_meta('comment', 'phone', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => __('Phone'),
        'single' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true
    ]);
}, 10 , 0);
```